# To access .UDL file from the sqlclient connection

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0

I have a .udl file with the following connection string in it

```
[oledb]
; Everything after this line is an OLE DB initstring
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial
Catalog=Client_DB050208;Data Source=IAEADB\IAEADBDEV;;Network Library=dbmssocn
```

Now I am trying to access this .udl file from the statement like

```
sConnectStr = "D:\PROBIS\ABC.udl" from one of my .vb class
```

**NOTE** : I need to use `SqlClient.SqlConnection`.

So can I access this `.udl` from `SqlClient.sqlConnection`.

Please get back to this question

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you could get this in a OLDEBConnection not SQL Connection. See [here](http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/7/38045.aspx)

Sort of makes sense. Otherwise just parse the file.